# integration and probability

Tags: probability, integration

Hi could someone please show me how the LHS is equal to the RHS? How did the integral limit change when adding the cdf? Thanks!

$$
\frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu - \ln K}{\zeta}} e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2  + \zeta \xi + \mu\right)}\, d \xi
= e^{\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2 - rT\right)} \Phi\left[-
\frac{\mu + \zeta^2 - \ln K}{\zeta}
\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\Big(-rT\Big)}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\zeta\xi+\mu\Big)}d\xi
&=&
e^{\Big(-rT\Big)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\zeta\xi-\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu\Big)}d\xi\\
&=&
e^{\Big(-rT\Big)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\zeta\xi-\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2\Big)}e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu\Big)}d\xi\\
&=&
e^{\Big(-rT\Big)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(\xi^2-\zeta)^2\Big)}e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu\Big)}d\xi\\
&=&
e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu-rT\Big)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\zeta)^2\Big)}d\xi\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, let $v=\xi-\zeta$. Then $dv=d\xi$. The lower limit remains as $-\infty$ and the upper limit is reduced by $\zeta$ and so is 
$$
-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}-\zeta = -\frac{\mu+\zeta^2-\ln K}{\zeta}
$$
Now the integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu-rT\Big)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\zeta)^2\Big)}d\xi
&=&
e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu-rT\Big)}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu+\zeta^2-\ln K}{\zeta}}e^{\Big(-\frac{1}{2}v^2\Big)}dv\Big)\\
&=&
e^{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2+\mu-rT\Big)}\Phi\Big[-\frac{\mu+\zeta^2-\ln K}{\zeta}\Big]\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ah, completing the square! I was desperately trying to figure out a proper u-substitution, but couldn't get it... Good trick :)

Comment: It is often useful when working with the normal pdf ;)

Comment: omg brilliant thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you cancel out some of the parts and simplify it begins to look more approachable: 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\mu - \ln K}{\zeta}} e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2  + \zeta \xi + \mu\right)}\, d \xi
= e^{\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2 \right)} \Phi\left[-
\frac{\mu - \ln K}{\zeta} - \zeta
\right]
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{A} e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2  + \zeta \xi + \mu\right)}\, d \xi
= e^{\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2 \right)} \Phi\left[A - \zeta
\right]
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{A} e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2  + \zeta \xi \right)}\, d \xi
= e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\xi^2 \right)} \Phi\left[A - \zeta
\right]
$$
this is looking like a standard integral.